# detect face from image and crop face from that photo

Tags: android, face-detection

I have done coding in that i am  successfully getting face with rectangle drawing now i want to crop that rectangle area. if there are many rectangle( mean many faces) than user can select one of the face or rectangle and that rectangle  areal should be cropped  can any body help me...

Below is my code

```
   class AndroidFaceDetector extends Activity {
public String path;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    path = bundle.getString("mypath");
    setContentView(new myView(this));

}

class myView extends View {

    private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
    private int numberOfFace = 5;
    private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
    private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
    float myEyesDistance;
    int numberOfFaceDetected;
    Bitmap myBitmap;

    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR");
        System.out.println("path = "+path);
        if (path != null) {
            BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
            imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
            imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
            myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
            myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);
            numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFaceDetector.this, "Please Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.println("ON DRAW IS CALLED");
        if (myBitmap != null) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
                Face face = myFace[i];
                PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
                face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
                myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
                canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance), (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance), (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance), myPaint);


            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no i am using android's native class like "FaceDetector"

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit - Hi i am looking for same thing. Were you able to figure it out? I would really like to know how you did it? Can you please share your code?

Comment: No @NoviceMe i still not found it :( you can do manually drag image and manually set it by this way i have done it

Comment: if you found your answer then please help other @Siddhpura Amit

Comment: @user3467110 sorry I still did not found :(

Comment: got it? same issue !

Comment: Create a new Canvas and copy the contents of the rect you already drew around the face to the new Canvas.